# Where should i put appUrl

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, strongloop

Hei,

I'm making an API with strongloop, which will send data for two ember apps: an marketing site & an app site. I would like to know where could i store the url for dev & prod envs?

Example of dev vars:

```
{
  "appUrl": "localhost:4200",
  "siteUrl": "localhost:4200"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/config.json) says, you define your server-side settings in `/server/config.json`

Default settings:

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 3000,
  "remoting": {
    ... // See below
  },
  "legacyExplorer": false
}
```

You can create [environment-specific configurations](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Environment-specific+configuration) by creating sets of configuration files per enviroment. Configuration file `/server/config.json` would in this case turn into `/server/config.{env}.json`, where `{env}` is a value of `NODE_ENV`.